# how to alternate or change words on Wordpress templates?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This is an example I'm trying to achieve.

Let say I have the USA states and each state has 5 cities and a custom template with content for each state.

I want to alternate/change the city names on each city page without changing the content.

If I visit California, then I click San Diego I want it to say blah blah blah Sandiego blah blah blah, then if I click on Los Angeles I want it to say blah blah blah Los Angeles blah blah blah.

I'm doing templates on the hierarchy that will have this content.

I'm trying to save time by creating one template and alternating the names of the cities around the text.

the content can stay the same, just the cities have to change one each state.

I created one template for each state, tho I need to use that same template for each city.

Comment: If you are using it as WP Pages, i did similar setup once, where States were parent pages, and all cities were child pages of that state. Template was same but had logic if parent then show state content, if child, then show city content... etc

Comment: Well, the content of the state will be unique not like the city. the city content will be different but the city name has to change so I can reuse it for every city on each state. I'm not trying to use the same content as the state. If I did not made myself clear last time my apologies.

Comment: For city pages.. just so i got it right, you will have same content in the template but city placeholder being changed with actual name? looks like it can be done, having own city template with content with city_name as search/replace operation and doing permalink add_rewrite_rule to catch the url and load the correct template/city. So   site.xyz/st/city  .. it tells us to load city template, with that city name, and also link to parent page i.e state...

Comment: Wow, this makes sense now. is there any links or pages with deeper examples of search and replace. I like the approach you are taking for this kind of project. Please submit it as an answer to my question or subject so I can give you credit for your answer.

Comment: Sure thank you I will write detailed answer now I know what you are after, for now you may see this example site on which I once implemented it , https://frontpointsecurityreviews.com/ on top right menu is called: Local, click on that and you will see local pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress to implement local pages for States and Cities we can use WordPress pages (we can go custom post route also but sometimes clients preferred root level pages for url without deep nesting i.e. site.abc/state instead of site.abc/cpt/state)

1. We can add States as Pages, to have State Full name and short-name tracking, we used it like: 
   Page name: State Full Name e.g. New York
   Slug : short-two letter code e.g. ny

So any given time once on the state page we have State Full name from title, state short-code from page slug etc..

2. For Cities we can make them look like child pages for state using addressing and WP permalink rules e.g. site.abc/st/city

This url gives us two clues, i.e it is child page so it is City page, so we will be loading city template for this page, and parent part tells which page/state it belongs to so we can fetch some data from there too like to show all other cities in the end from same state etc.

**For URL Parsing: (Untested code, just for ideas)**

```
function custom_endpoints() {
add_rewrite_rule(
    '([^/]{2})/([^/]*)',
    'index.php?state=$matches[1]&city=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);

add_rewrite_tag( '%state%', '([^&]+)' );
add_rewrite_tag( '%city%', '([^&]+)' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_endpoints' );
```

**Now we can add those rewrite tags into query as query_vars**

```
function em_query_vars($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'state');
    array_push($vars, 'city');
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars','em_query_vars');
```

**Now For template loading we can use those query tags: (Untested Code, only for ideas)**

`add_filter('template_include', 'custom_function_for_templates', 1, 1);`

```
 function custom_function_for_templates($template) {

    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['state']) && isset($wp_query->query_vars['city'])) {
$slug = $wp_query->query_vars['city'];

return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ). '/templates/city-template.php';
    }
    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['state'])) {

        return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ). '/templates/state-template.php';
    }


    return $template;
}
```

Lastly in the template, you can use current query tag for City to replace wherever in the content you have %%city%% and %%st%% and %%state%% tags to replace with correct city name to display the page with content relevant to current city and state.

Hope it will give you enough ideas to implement it as per your current setup. Code I have included is not tested so it may not work. But Hooks and Filter from WordPress Api used are correct ones so you can always hook your own logic/function to those steps to make it happen.

**Edit: Search Replace Operations on Php Level in the Template**

```
$content = str_replace("%%city%%", $new_page, $content);
$content = str_replace("%%state%%", get_the_title($state), $content);
$content = str_replace("%%st%%", strtoupper(get_post_field( 'post_name',$state)), $content);
```

Here you will see I am search/replacing the content's any tags used there

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I get it to a certain extent and I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: the place where I'm confused, is that I'm using a child theme. So do I add a brand new JS file to it and link it? or do I add this functions in the parent JS file?

Comment: @CesarDiaz It is all php code I suggested, no JS code. Looks like you confusing it with something else? Or you are asking other question i.e. how to add JS file to child theme? I would suggest enquing in functions.php using WP JS enqueue hook, or simply google it or ask separate question for that and you will get detailed answer by me or someone available at that time.

Comment: I need more information on how to implement the sample code you just showed me,  please. I email you in your website.